# Javascript scroll function niceScroll

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, scroll

I have a chat window where i have applied the NiceScroll function, Its working fine in Google Chrome, but in IE and IE Edge, its not working at all.

```
chat_body.scrollTop(chat_body.get(0).scrollHeight, -1).niceScroll({
                                    cursorcolor: 'rgba(66, 66, 66, 0.20)',
                                    cursorwidth: "4px",
                                    cursorborder: '0px'
                                }).resize();
```

Please suggest what could be the issue and how to resolve this.
regards,
Naveen Jain

Comment: Did you get any error while using the website in the IE browser? If yes, please inform us about the error message. also, try to provide the sample code that we can try to run in the IE browser to check for the issue. I try to make a test with this sample and it is working fine with the IE browser. http://embed.plnkr.co/e8gnGeq7Ek24MN9QPp7e/

Answer (score 0):

#### First port of call would be the GitHub project page for this software

https://github.com/inuyaksa/jquery.nicescroll/blob/master/README.md

It does say that it should work on IE and Edge (remember there is no such thing as IE Edge).

Next step is to prepare an example piece of code. Make it as simple as possible, yet sufficient for anyone to replicate the working / non-working behaviour in the various browsers. What you presented isn't enough, because it doesn't have enough context: it will generate an error on any browser, because your code doesn't itself contain a definition of "chat_body" etc. Remove everything that isn't needed, for example cut down the number of cursor characteristics if possible.

If you don't get a response on the niceScroll github page, come back here and try again, but this time use the "<>" icon to enter a code snippet that self-sufficiently generates the two behaviours in the various browsers. This will maximise the chance of a solution here.

If this explanation is sufficiently polite and helpful, please mark it as correc. 8-)